# Unable to handle the exception properly

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

In the below code first insert statement is,

```
insert into customer_master select max(customerid)+1,customer_name from customer_master 
where customer_name not in (select customername from customer_master);
```

Am getting null value insert error for this. Yes, that is right.

But it is stopping below statements of the block from executing.

```
insert into customer_account_mapping select customerid,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)),cost from customer_master where customername=customer_name and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from customer_account_mapping);

insert into user_permissions select distinct user_id,sales_person_name,sales_mgr_name,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)) from user_permissions where sales_person_name=sales_person and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from user_permissions) and rownum<2 ;
```

Complete code is given below.

```
create or replace
procedure dashboard_addtion
        (customer_name  varchar2,pcd parray,acd aarray,sales_person varchar2,cost number)
IS

begin
insert into customer_master select max(customerid)+1,customer_name from customer_master 
where customer_name not in (select customername from customer_master);
for i in 1..acd.count loop
insert into customer_account_mapping select customerid,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)),cost from customer_master where customername=customer_name and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from customer_account_mapping);
insert into user_permissions select distinct user_id,sales_person_name,sales_mgr_name,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)) from user_permissions where sales_person_name=sales_person and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from user_permissions) and rownum<2 ;
commit;
end loop;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
end;
```

Comment: What is a "null value insert error"? Can you provide the exact error and the DDL of your table, including indexes and constraints? P.S. investigate sequences.

Comment: @AlexPoole -  This is a slight variation on that question.

Comment: @APC - isn't it just changing which `insert` statement needs the `begin`/`end` wrapper?

Comment: @AlexPoole - probably.  I think both questions are misguided, because they both violate the notion of transactional integrity.

Comment: max(customerid)+1 is going to cause problems if multiple sessions run this code at the same time, or if customer_master is ever empty

Answer (score 1):

> Am getting null value insert error for this. Yes, that is right.
>
> But it is stopping below statements of the block from executing.

The exception caused process flow to go to the EXCEPTION handler section.  That is the end of the program block.  So processing stops after handling the exception.  This is standard. So in fact, your have titled your question wrongly, because this is the proper way to handle exceptions.  The whole point is to preserve [the ACIDity of the transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). Why would you want to continue processing if the first part of your program fails?

Although, having described this as the proper way I feel I must say that "handling" exceptions by simply using DBMS_OUTPUT is extremely bad practice.  That won't work in production code because calling progarm won't know an exception occurred.  Your procedure needs to log the error and then re-raise the exception.  Anything else is just asking for trouble.